# Creating new java.sql.Date using rJava

Tags: r

I've tried the following: `.jnew("java/sql/Date", 1912324L))` (using the [rJava](http://www.rforge.net/rJava/) package) and get the following:

> Error in .jnew("java/sql/Date", 1912324L) : 
>     java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Same error when I try `.jnew("java/util/Date", 1912324L)`.

Any ideas about why this is happening?

NB: This works fine `.jnew("java/lang/String", "s")`

Obligatory session_info():

```
Session info --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
 system   x86_64, darwin14.4.0        
 ui       RStudio (0.99.441)          
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_AU.UTF-8                 
 tz       Australia/Sydney            

Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package   * version date       source        
 crayon      1.3.0   2015-06-05 CRAN (R 3.2.1)
 curl        0.9     2015-06-19 CRAN (R 3.2.1)
 devtools  * 1.8.0   2015-05-09 CRAN (R 3.2.1)
 digest      0.6.8   2014-12-31 CRAN (R 3.2.1)
 git2r       0.10.1  2015-05-07 CRAN (R 3.2.1)
 memoise     0.2.1   2014-04-22 CRAN (R 3.2.1)
 Rcpp        0.11.6  2015-05-01 CRAN (R 3.2.1)
 rJava     * 0.9-6   2013-12-24 CRAN (R 3.2.1)
 rversions   1.0.1   2015-06-06 CRAN (R 3.2.1)
 testthat  * 0.10.0  2015-05-22 CRAN (R 3.2.1)
 xml2        0.1.1   2015-06-02 CRAN (R 3.2.1)
```

And...running Java 1.6:

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-466.1, mixed mode)
```

Comment: The constructor of `Date` takes a `long` and you are passing an `int`. The other (deprecated) constructor works: `.jnew("java/sql/Date", 115L,11L,10L)`.

Answer (score 5):

The constructor of `java.sql.Date` takes a `long` as argument and you are passing an `int` instead. Since R doesn't have native `float` and `long` types, `rJava` provides the `.jfloat` and `.jlong` functions to convert numeric R vectors. This works:

```
.jnew("java/sql/Date", .jlong(1912324))
```

Keep in mind that you have to provide the number of milliseconds from the 1970-01-01, so it's highly unlikely that the value you provided is what you intend.